# How to pass variable one page to another page in opencart

Tags: php, opencart, pinterest

Please give me a ideas i have to created a variable like ($data['image2']) i want pass one page to other page how please help me.Actually,(What ever i added in product(image) for admin panel(opencart) that product image automatically should go to pinterest account i have tried but almost done i doing some miner issue i don't know please help me this.)

Here my code:controller:

```
 if (isset($this->request->post['image'])) {

                $data['image2'] = $this->request->post['image'];
                //print_r($data['image']);die;
            }
          // print_r($data['image2']);
//--------Post image-------///
 //-------------curl starting---------------//
                $url = 'http://localhost/mspink_new/pintest.php';
                $ch = curl_init();
                curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_URL, $url);
                curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POST, count(0));
                curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, 1);
                //execute post
                $result = curl_exec($ch);
                print_r($result);die;
                curl_close($ch);
```

I want pass the value to pinterest.php file how.

```
<?php
//$get =$_get('image');die;
//$image = $_GET['image'];
//print_r($image);die;
require_once "Pinterest.class.php";
// Create the pinterest object and log in
$p = new Pinterest();


$p->login("loginid", "password");
if( $p->is_logged_in() )
    echo "Success, we're logged in\n";

//$image = $p->generate_image_preview("slider-old.jpg");

// if (isset($_POST)) {

//      $image ="image";
// }
// print_r($image);die;
// Set up the pin
//$p->pin_url = "http://yellow5.com";
$p->pin_url = "http://www.mspinkpanther.com/";
$p->pin_description = "My awesome pin";
$p->pin_image_preview = $p->generate_image_preview('slider.jpg');
// Get the boards
$p->get_boards();
// Pin to the board called "Items"
if( !isset($p->boards['Items']) ) {
    echo "For testing, please create a board called 'Items' and try again!\n";
    exit;
}
$p->pin($p->boards['Items']);
// And we're done
echo "Hooray!\n";
```

Comment: did you mean how to pass controller to view

Comment: not view file that is also normal php file only sir.

Comment: what is the name of the function in controller

Comment: function name is Add().

Comment: Hi Mehravish Temkar,,, im got post image value & i want pass other file.

Comment: $variable_to_be_passed = $this->load->controller('controller_name/Add');
and in Add() -- return $variable_to_be_passed;

Comment: not working sir.

Comment: can you show me what did you try, also if there was any error

Comment: try this chage  curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POST, count(0)); to  curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POST, $data); you will post you image value to pinterest.php, and save in $image = $_POST['image2'];